# ORA-14450: attempt to access the transactional temp table already in use

Tags: sql, oracle, temporary

Folks, I'm with this error:

> ORA-14450: attempt to access the transactional temp table already in
>   use.

Can someone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The session which locks the table is not committed/roll backed the changes.
Find out which session blocks that table and kill that session. or wait till that session commit/rollback the changes.